# JUnit/HSQLDB: How to get around errors with Oracle syntax when testing using HSQLDB (no privilege and/or no DUAL object)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, junit, hsqldb

I have DAO code which contains some JDBC with Oracle-specific syntax, for example:

```
select count(*) cnt from DUAL 
where exists (select null from " + TABLE_NAME + "
              where LOCATION = '" + location + "')")
```

I am running JUnit tests on this DAO method using an in-memory HSQLDB database.  Apparently the DUAL table is Oracle specific and causes an error when I run the test:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; 
    bad SQL grammar [select count(*) cnt from DUAL where exists 
                    (select null from ESRL_OBSERVATIONS where LOCATION = '/path1')];
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: user lacks privilege or object 
    not found: DUAL
```

Can anyone suggest anything I can do to get around this issue?  I am using Hibernate to create the schema -- perhaps there's a setting I can make in my Hibernate properties which will enable support for Oracle style syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Hibernate 3.6 with HSQLDB 2.0.1 or later, you can use a connection property `sql.syntax_ora=true` on your connection URL. This enables the DUAL table together with some other Oracle specific syntax.

You probably need a few more connection properties for behaviour that is not covered by the main property. See: 
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_compatibility_oracle

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. Unfortunately I can't get it to work.  My URL is 'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true'.  I am using Hibernate version 3.6.0 and HSQLDB version 2.0.1-rc3.  Is there something else required that I may be missing?

Comment: Something interesting is happening -- when I run the test now from an Ant build script then the test passes, but if I run the test from within an Eclipse IDE (Run As -> JUnit Test) then I still get the original error.  WTF?

Comment: Nevermind -- I had an older version of the HSQLDB JAR file being pulled into the Eclipse build path from another Eclipse project which caused the error.  Once that was rectified all went well.  Thanks again for the expert advice.

Answer (score 6):

The HSQL "Oracle style syntax" can also be enabled via a SQL command

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE
```

See [12.30](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_sql_conformance) . It's an alternative to the property `sql.syntax_ora=true` as suggested in fredt's answer. It may be more practical in some cases : the flag can be set via JDBC after the HSQL database has been started.

Comment: This worked for me. I added this to my integration test configuration where dataSource was instantiated.
`dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement("SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE").execute();`

Comment: @PrashantVishwakarma for some reason this worked for me, whereas adding `sql.syntax_ora=true` did not

Answer (score 3):

Create a table called DUAL with one column, "DUMMY", in the HSQLDB database. Insert one row, value 'X'.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, however I am not creating the tables manually or programmatically, they are being generated in-memory by Hibernate when the tests launch.  The tests run each time the code is built by Ant or Maven.

Comment: @JamesAdams You may still create a table via custom script (using spring of course) `<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:script.sql"/>
 </jdbc:embedded-database>`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but it is possible to use the custom url to set oracle dialect. I created a custom data-source factory with updated url and injected the same while initializing the DB.

```
//Custom class
public class CusstomSimpleDriverDataSourceFactory implements DataSourceFactory {

    private final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();

    @Override
    public ConnectionProperties getConnectionProperties() {
        return new ConnectionProperties() {
            @Override
            public void setDriverClass(Class<? extends Driver> driverClass) {
                dataSource.setDriverClass(driverClass);
            }

            @Override
            public void setUrl(String url) {
                System.out.println("Existing url: " + url);
                String newUrl = url+";sql.syntax_ora=true";
                System.out.println("New url: " + newUrl);
                dataSource.setUrl(newUrl);
            }

            @Override
            public void setUsername(String username) {
                dataSource.setUsername(username);
            }

            @Override
            public void setPassword(String password) {
                dataSource.setPassword(password);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return this.dataSource;
    }

}

Then in the configuration you can use
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
              .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
              .setDataSourceFactory(new CusstomSimpleDriverDataSourceFactory())
              .addScript("ddl_script") 
              .addScript("dml_script")
              .build();
    }
```