# 'InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException' when using Sequence with HSQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I am using JPA with Hibernate/Oracle and for test phase, using HSQL. I have defined the datasource as specified in this  [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628857/junit-hsqldb-how-to-get-around-errors-with-oracle-syntax-when-testing-using-hsq) but did not help.

**Note**: I am running a Liquibase script to generate the Schema.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="DM_UW_REF_RULES_RSLT_UWSCOREID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_UW_SCORE_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DM_UW_REF_RULES_RSLT_UWSCOREID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name="UW_SCORE_ID")
```

The HSQL datasource and entityManagerFactory bean definitions are as follows

```
dmDs(BasicDataSource) {
driverClassName = 'org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver'
url = 'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true'
username = 'sa'
password = ''
}

entityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
    dataSource = ref('dmDs')
    packagesToScan = "com.abc.dm.model"
    jpaVendorAdapter = ref('hibjpa')
    jpaPropertyMap = ["connection.driver_class": "org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver", 'hibernate.dialect':'org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect','show_sql': "true"]
}
```

Exception Trace:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SEQ_UW_SCORE_ID.NEXTVAL
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property for table generation.

You can alternatively use the generic javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action property.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using liquibase to run the DDLs including Sequence.