# HSQLDB ROWNUM compatibility with Oracle

Tags: oracle, hsqldb, rownum

THe [HSQLDB changelog](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/changelist_2_0.txt) states that `ROWNUM()` was added in `v2.2.0` which I am using without any problems when running integration tests against the in-memory HSQLDB.

However I want to run the same tests against a real Oracle 10g database, but the query fails because the pseudo-column is called `ROWNUM`. Is there an easy way write a single query string that works in both environments?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The ROWNUM() function is available by default in HSQLDB 2.2.x and later. If you enable Oracle syntax compatibility mode, you can also use ROWNUM.

This statement enables it:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE
```

Or use the connection property `sql.syntax_ora=true`

Comment: Perfect! I did not know that existed :-)

Comment: I just found a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579078/how-to-use-hsqldb-in-oracle-query-syntax-mode

Comment: Note that the `sql.syntax_ora=true` must be given in the connection URL: e.g. `<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:spring;sql.syntax_ora=true"/>`, not in a `<property name="sql.syntax_ora" value="true"/>`