# How to retrieve data from HSQL within a row range?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have worked with oracle where to select data within a particular row range the query is :

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE rownum>0 AND rownum<=10
```

What would be the corresponding query in HSQL?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612862/hsqldb-rownum-compatibility-with-oracle) works for you

Comment: `rownum > 0` is useless in Oracle and if you intend to use e.g. `rownum > 5` then that [won't work](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) in Oracle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HSQLDB supports the `LIMIT` and  `OFFSET` keyword

```
select *
from some_table
limit 10
offset 2;
```

Note that `limit` and `offset` make no sense without an `order by` clause (which is true for Oracle as well).

HSQLDB also supports the ANSI SQL standard `fetch first x rows` but that will require the use of an `order by`

```
select *
from some_table
order by some_column
offset 2 rows
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

The above is also supported by Oracle since 12.1

See the manual for details
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_slicing

Comment: OP asked for range

Comment: `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tableName` also works