# Sybase ASE to HSQLDB JUnit java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: type not found or user lacks privilege

Tags: java, junit, prepared-statement, hsqldb, sap-ase

In a project I have inherited, there is a prepared statement defined as:

```
<select id="GET_FILE_BY_FILE_ID" parameterType="long" resultType="com.employer.my.File" statementType="PREPARED">
  SELECT  
    file_id fileId,
    file_name name,
    file_type type,
    CASE WHEN file_data_long is null THEN convert (image, file_data_short) ELSE file_data_long END AS fileData
    FROM FILES_TABLE
    WHERE file_id = #{id}
</select>
```

This SQL statements works fine at runtime, with a `Sybase ASE` database.

But the JUnit that executes it (as part of the build), keeps failing with

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: type not found or user lacks privilege: FILE_DATA_SHORT
```

I tracked this error to the CASE THEN convert statement:

```
    CASE WHEN file_data_long is null THEN convert (image, file_data_short) ELSE file_data_long END AS fileData
```

That is, the following prepared statement, does NOT produce said error:

```
<select id="GET_FILE_BY_FILE_ID" parameterType="long" resultType="com.employer.my.File" statementType="PREPARED">
  SELECT  
    file_id fileId,
    file_name name,
    file_type type,
    file_data_short fileData
    FROM FILES_TABLE
    WHERE file_id = #{id}
</select>
```

Suspecting this may have to do with `convert`, I came across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32585642/8080472) which suggests that to run HSQLDB with the a non-HSQLDB dialect one must first enable that syntax compatibility mode on HSQLDB.

A similar hint was found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23613546/8080472).

With that I have been able to find Sybase specific directive in [the hsqldb.org doc](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/compatibility-chapt.html):

"Use SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MSS TRUE or the equivalent URL property **sql.syntax_mss=true** to enable support for the `CONVERT(<type definition>, <expression)` function with switched order of arguments"

Well, I did just that, adding `sql.syntax_mss=true` to the project's HSDLDB properties:

```
HSQLDB(org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.class, org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.class, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mymemdb;sql.syntax_mss=true", new TestMapperHsqlDB(), true)
```

But that didn't help: I am still getting that dreaded exception when running the JUnit test (only then. That query runs fine at runtime or from DBeaver).

Any idea what else I could be missing in attempting to make this work for both runtime (Sybase/ASE) and JUnit (HSDLDB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, for the benefit of others who may be perplexed by a similar encounter:

After attempting the syntax/dialect modifier (see OP), I found [this list of HSQLDB built it in functions](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_general_functions), where the 'image' is not a supported type by HSQLDB, so `convert` has no chance of succeeding...

That prompted me to look for a solution/workaround where the SQL itself would be slightly different based on the database on which it is running:

```
<select id="GET_FILE_BY_FILE_ID" parameterType="long" resultType="com.employer.my.File" statementType="PREPARED">
  SELECT  
    file_id fileId,
    file_name name,
    file_type type,
    <if test="_databaseId == 'SYBASE'">
      CASE WHEN file_data_long is null THEN convert (image, file_data_short) ELSE file_data_long END AS fileData
    </if>  
    <if test="_databaseId == 'HSQLDB'">
        CASE WHEN FFT.file_data_long is null  THEN FFT.file_data_short  ELSE FFT.file_data_long  END AS fileData
    </if>
    FROM FILES_TABLE FFT
    WHERE file_id = #{id}
</select>
```

And this -- works like a charm.