# Configure HSQLDB with maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, hsqldb

I'm developing a Spring application where everything is configured with maven (in `pom.xml`). My application uses a PostgreSQL database, but unit tests use an in-memory HSQLDB database.

I just run into an issue with `TEXT` columns because they are not supported natively by HSQLDB. In my entity class I have :

```
private @Column(columnDefinition = "text") String propertyName;
```

This works fine with Postgres, but HSQLDB is generating the following error : `type not found or user lacks privilege: TEXT`. The table is not created, and of course as a result most of my tests fail.

I found that I need to [activate PostgreSQL compatibility](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#N1582A) in order for this to work by setting `sql.syntax_pgs` to `true`.

My question is : where do I put this setting ? I would like to put it in `pom.xml` because everything is configured there, but I don't know where.

For exemple I have :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=test</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Can I somehow add an `<argLine>` with this setting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add hsqldb dependency it uses default connection properties. You can  override these properties in property file or through other configuration as per your requirement. You can set "sql.syntax_pgs=true" to HSQLDB connection url. For example in case of spring boot this will be like below.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
              <argLine>-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:PUBLIC;sql.syntax_pgs=true</argLine>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in the Datasource configuration as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579078/how-to-use-hsqldb-in-oracle-query-syntax-mode)

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:PUBLIC;sql.syntax_pgs=true" />
   <property name="username" value="sa" />
   <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Where do I put this ? Also I only want this to take effect when using the `test` profile.

Comment: you need to put this when you are configuring the HSQLDB for the tests. This property will be set for all the test using hsqldb.

Comment: I'm not configuring HSQLDB anywhere, I just added it in `pom.xml` as a dependency, it's then used automatically by maven when running tests.